# Need to prove $P(A \triangle B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

Need to prove $P(A \triangle B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A \cap B)$

where $A \triangle B= (A \cap \overline{B}) \cup (B \cap \overline{A})$

Comment: How about drawing the Venn diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $P(A△B) = 1- (P(A \cap B) + P(A' \cap B'))$ where $A'$ and $B'$ are respectively the compliments of $A$ and $B$.
Hence, 
$$ \begin{align} & P(A△B) \\ &= 1 - ((P(A \cap B) + (1 - (P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B))) \\ &= -(P(A \cap B) + P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) \\ & = P(A)+P(B)−2P(A \cap B) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$(A \triangle B) \cup (A\cap B) = (A\cap \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap B) \cup (A\cap B) = (A\cap \overline{B})\cup  B=A \cup B.$$
Likewise,
$$(A \triangle B) \cap (A\cap B) = \phi.$$
Consequently, 
$$P((A \triangle B) \cup (A\cap B)) = P(A \triangle B) + P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B)=?$$

Comment: could you explain me this? I am really bad at this...